# Building R package with C++11 & Rcpp on Windows

Tags: windows, r, c++11, mingw, rcpp

**SYSTEM SPEC:**

- **OS** - Windows 7 Professional & Mac OS X 10.6.8
- **MinGW** - 4.7.3 and above
- **R** - 3.0.1
- **Rcpp** - 0.10.4

I cannot compile a working package with C++11 code in it on Windows (neither a 32 or 64 bit version). MinGW compiles and installs the package, but using functions that call C++11 code crashes R. I am using C++11's *random* library - specifically, a humble binomial distribution with Mersenne Twister generator.

I am confident that my code is correct as its UNIX version (compiled on Mac OS X using gcc 4.7.3) is working as intended without any problems at all.

The problem is not in Rcpp or RcppArmadillo - in fact, I was able to make my package operational by using Armadillo's random number generator. However, I am extremely keen on being able to use C++11 in the future, especially  library.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you have to do anything non-standard to use MinGW 4.7.3 instead of the one in Rtools(e.g. rebuild R & Rcpp)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have C++11 examples at the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) -- you could try re-running those at your end.

Particularly, [this post creates RNG draws](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/timing-normal-rngs/) using three different ways: R, Boost and C++11.  Can you see if that works for you?

Comment: Yes, it does - the problem was with the seed I was using. I used std::random_device - and it looks like Windows is not supporting it. Thank you for clarifying this!